# gasを用いたLINEbot で、user から取得したメッセージと文字列を比較する方法

Tags: google-apps-script, line

[image: コードです]

コードの部分で
`if(userMessage.includes("mon"))`
をどのように記述したら良いか教えていただきたいです。
今の現状ではエラーは出ませんが、うまく作動しません。
（LINEでmonと打っても反応がない）

Comment: こんなの [【Google Apps Script(GAS)】ブレークポイントの設定とデバッグ実行(GAS入門)](https://vba-gas.info/gas-breakpoint-debug) でブレークポイント設定して中身を確認してはどうでしょう？

Comment: ソースコードはキャプチャ(=画像)ではなく、なるべく文字のまま貼り付けてください。画像にしてしまうと回答の際に引用等が難しくなります。

Comment: 中身がまだLINE からメッセージを送信していないのでundefinedとなってしまいます。。